# Facebook Flash AS3 application - swc does not work

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript-3, flash

I've downloaded the [GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads/detail?name=GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc) and discovered it does not work as expected.

```
 Facebook.init("APP_CODE",handler);
```

For example the handler, never gets called.

My goal is to develop an AS3 app with no Javascript "helpers". is that possible? where can I find some resources to get me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook ActionScript SDK's web implementation builds on a JavaScript SDK.  Look at the [Adobe tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_pt3.html) to see how to set up the web page in which you embed your SWF.